# Creating custom types that extend certain objects

Tags: unity, c#

Really new to C# scripting. I'm trying to extend a `TileBase` type object to be able to hold custom methods and variables.

I want to create a pathfinding script and I need to store certain information for each tile. Something like this:

```
TileBase startPoint = tilemap.GetTile (tilemap.WorldToCell (transform.position));

startPoint.customVariable = 5;
```

Is there a way to extend TileBase into a new type and create custom methods inside it? How can I achieve this in Unity?

Comment: Extension/inheritance is often not the best way to go in Unity. You may want to consider storing these variables in a separate array in your pathfinder, indexed by tile position, or use [the principle of composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Yes, you can subclass the TileBase to add your own properties and functions, or override existing ones. [Here's an example of someone doing that](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-add-behaviors-to-a-tileasset.526036/#post-3458440). Also get comfortable with what [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) are (in case they may cover your use case) as well as understanding how you can composit a single object with different classes/ behaviors, as DMGregory mentions. Knowing all of those tools helps you find the right mix for each job. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Tiles are Scriptable Objects in Unity. See official manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-ScriptableTiles.html

So yes, you can extend either TileBase or Tile. The manual has an example: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-ScriptableTiles-Example.html

Essentially:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class MyTile : Tile {
   [SerializeField] private int movementCost { get; }

   [...the rest...]
}
```